# Separable bidual but nonseparable third dual

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Does there exist a Banach space $X$ such that $X^{**}$ is separable but $X^{***}$ is non-separable?

More generally, for every natural $n$ can someone construct an example of Banach space $X$ such that $X^{n}$ is separable but not $X^{n+1}$?

Comment: Why do not you accept the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes to both.  Lindenstrauss extended James' construction to show that for any separable $X$ there is a separable $Y$ s.t. $Y^{**}/Y$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X$. Induct on that.  Spaces built that way are called James-Lindenstrauss spaces. Another proof is contained in my "Factoring Weakly Compact Operator" paper with Davis, Figiel and Pelczynski.

Comment: Is $Y^{***}$ nonseparable easy?

Comment: @NikWeaver: Apply the Lindenstrauss construction with $X=\ell_1$. The lifting property of $\ell_1$ yields a (complemented) subspace of $Y^{\ast\ast}$ that is isomorphic to $\ell_1$ (not sure if this qualifies as easy though?)

Comment: Nice! Thank you.